Code organization with Flask to avoid global scope to run in multiple places
An app made with Flask often has a structure like this (it can be used both directly with python3 app.py or launched with gunicorn):
# imports
from flask import Flask
from flask_session import Session

# global scope calls
app = Flask(__name__)         # app is defined in globals, for it to be available as decorator
app.secret_key = 'abcd'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)       

# function definitions
def init_db():
    pass

@app.route('/')               
def index():
    pass

# other routes

# global scope calls again
init_db()                     # in the global scope but this time, at the end!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Is there a standard Flask code organization that avoids having to have code to run at different places of the global scope?
Pseudo-code, just to get the idea:
from flask import FlaskServer, route
class MyServer(FlaskServer):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @route("/")
    def index(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = MyServer()
    s.run()


Have you considered the application factory pattern?https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/stable/patterns/appfactories/

This will generate a project for you using best practices including what EAW mentioned with the app factory pattern (which works quite well): https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask

Coming from here. I don't have a strong opinion on this, but using templates and existing conventions sounds like a good place to start. Good luck!
